# how to get rid of text beside emacs toolbar buttons

Tags: emacs

Running under ubuntu, emacs has a text description of buttons in the toolbar, even have something like

|(separator)

which is really annoying.

Comment: Is this the case for you even when you start emacs as `emacs -Q`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the variable `tool-bar-style`.  You can do this with `C-h v`.  You can then either click the "customize" button at the bottom of the help buffer, or you can just evaluate

```
(setq tool-bar-style 'image)
```